# Restrict Jenkins declarative pipeline agents at the server level?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently looking into replacing a number of existing Jenkins builds with declarative pipeline builds.

The Jenkinsfile allows me to specify agents in a number of ways (name, labels, docker image), but what I really need is a way to restrict this at the server level.

The goal is to force all pipeline-based builds to run inside Docker containers, and not directly on the node.

Is this possible? If so: how?